# Swift NSUserNotification doesn't show while app is active

Tags: swift, osx-yosemite, nsusernotification, nsusernotificationcenter

I am new to OSX development and I am making an app which fires a notification when something happens. But it isn't showing the notification when the app is the key app, as it is the default behavior. I want to show them even when the app IS the key app. 
However I only found solutions to this matter that were written in objective-c  but right now I am working with Swift. I was wondering how I could I implement it with Swift.

Comment: Did you set your application delegate as the NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate?

Comment: I did not. I saw you needed to do that. But how can I make the further steps?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To ensure the notifications are always shown you'll need to set a delegate for `NSUserNotificationCenter` and implement `userNotificationCenter(center:shouldPresentNotification:) -> Bool`.  The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate/userNotificationCenter:shouldPresentNotification:) says this message is

> Sent to the delegate when the user notification center has decided not
>   to present your notification.

You can implement the delegate in any class of your choosing.  Here is an example:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        NSUserNotificationCenter.defaultUserNotificationCenter().delegate = self
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(center: NSUserNotificationCenter, shouldPresentNotification notification: NSUserNotification) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
```

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks! So the arrow is like a return type? Like I said, I am new to OSX and Swift development, I am trying to learn.

Comment: Yes, `->` indicates the return type of a function.

Comment: Ah, I see. I am more used to C# and PHP so it is challenging learn swift. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I got it working by using an extension: (swift 3) https://gist.github.com/eonist/903e46b811c5eeeef84da2015c567b1b